# vb.net reports tablix aplhanumeric sort

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have the following code and it works in sql management studio, but not with vb.net :

```
Dim opdragsorteeraplhanumeries As New SqlCommand
    konneksie.ConnectionString = "Data Source=GIDEON-E-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS2014;Initial Catalog=SkeduleringDatabasis;Integrated Security=True"
    konneksie.Open()
    opdragsorteeraplhanumeries.Connection = konneksie
    opdragsorteeraplhanumeries.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Oesskattings " & _
    "ORDER BY " & _
        "CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(blokno) = 1 THEN right(Replicate('0',21) + blokno, 21) " & _
           "WHEN ISNUMERIC(blokno) = 0 then Left(blokno + Replicate('',21), 21) " & _
          " ELSE blokno " & _
        " End"

    opdragsorteeraplhanumeries.ExecuteNonQuery()
    konneksie.Close()
    MsgBox("Alphanumeries gesorteer")
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with the tablix - you need to sort the data in the table, either in the query, or the dataset; and for this you have not supplied enough information. For instance, do you mean it must be sorted such that the first n numeric chars are sorted in numeric order, followed by text? for instance, where would '34-BNW go'? '34_bnw'?

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Sub Main()
    Dim input = "5-BOP,2,11,4_ANW"
    Dim result = sortString(input)
End Sub

Private Function sortString(input As String) As String
    Dim result = input.Split(",").
        OrderBy(Function(s) Integer.Parse(Regex.Replace(s, "[^0-9.]", ""))).
        Aggregate(Function(p1, p2) p1 & "," & p2)
    Return result
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give some additional information. Do all entries consist of a unique number followed by non-numeric data, and you want to sort by the number? Or are other combinations possible. Like, could there be "3-5" and "3-43"? In that case would 3-5 come before 3-43? Or could there be "3-Y-5" and "3-X-17"? If so which should come first? How about "3-X-5" and "3-5-X"? Etc.

Also, when you give your list of example values, is that supposed to represent data from one record or many? That is, do you have a record with one field that contains "5-BOP,2,11,4_ANW"? Or do you mean that one record has "5-BOP", another has "2", etc?

In any case, neither SQL nor any built-in function that I know of will do the kind of sort you describe -- effectively breaking a field into pieces and sorting on only one of those pieces or having rules for how to relate the different pieces.

If this is a sort that is specific to one report, you could sort the records in memory. If it's a sort that is commonly used throughout your system, you probably want to be able to do it on the database. The common way to do this is to create a field that has the data faked out into something where a conventional SQL sort works. Like if the reality is that there's a number and then some extra stuff after the number that doesn't matter, then create a field that just holds the number and is declared as an integer. If you need to sort on number, and within that sort alphabetically on whatever follows, then have a field for the number and a field for the rest of the stuff. If it's more complicated than that, you might need to create a field with things padded to maximum size and then concatenated. Like if you always have a number that's a maximum of 3 digits, followed by up to 4 characters, you could turn these values into "005BOP", "002", "011", and "004ANW".

I once built a system where I made a SQL user-defined function that read the messy number and formatted it sort of like I describe above, and then I created an index on this field. That saved on having the same data in the record twice.

In general, if you have a field that is made up of multiple pieces like this, it's usually better to have separate fields in the database and put them together when you need that, rather than one field that you try to take apart. It's almost always easier to put things together than to take them apart.